# How to remove default Spring JMS Template headers when sending a message to an MQ?

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq

Using Java/Spring to interact with a WebSphere MQ and trying to send a message to it, Spring keeps adding the following header information to it:

`RFH Ì ¸MQSTR ¸ <mcd><Msd>jms_text</Msd></mcd> <jms><Dst>queue:///MY.QUEUE.INFORMATION.TEST</Dst><Rto>queue:///MY.QUEUE.INFORMATION.TEST</Rto><Tms>123456789</Tms><Dlv>2</Dlv></jms>BEGINNING_OF_MY_PAYLOAD`

How would I remove everything and only send my payload? One could refer to my payload in the snippet above as `BEGINNING_OF_MY_PAYLOAD`.

Here's the function I'm using:

```
public void sendMessage(final String text) {
        this.jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                Message message = session.createTextMessage(text);
                destination = session.createQueue("MY.QUEUE.INFORMATION.TEST");
                springJmsConsumer.setDestination(destination);
                message.setJMSReplyTo(destination);
                return message;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. Anytime we want to remove headers from our Spring JMS message being sent out to a WebSphere MQ, always use the following:

`this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("queue:///YOUR.QUEUE.NAME.HERE?targetClient=1", text);`

So now my function looks like:

```
public void send(String text) {
        this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("queue:///MY.QUEUE.INFORMATION.TEST?targetClient=1", text);
}
```