# Spring Integration writing to IBM MQ

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-integration-dsl

Using Boot 2.2.2 and Spring Integration 5.2.2 interacting with another application via IBM MQ Series 9; the messages need to be purely text (not JMS). SI can get the text messages correctly, however I cannot seem to put to MQ without a JMS header.

Using JMS **without** SI, I can write a pure text message by using;

```
    jmsTemplate.send(myQueue, new MessageCreator() {

        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            return session.createTextMessage(message);
        }
    });
```

When using SI I have the following;

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow toQueue(
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
            @Value("${app.outQueue}") String myQueue
    ) {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("myIncomingChannel")
            .headerFilter("*")
            .handle(
                Jms
                    .outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
                    .configureJmsTemplate(jts -> jts.jmsMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter()))
                    .extractPayload(true)
                    .destination(myQueue)
            )
            .get();
    }
```

I have tried 8 combinations of;

1. With/without `configureJmsTemplate`
2. `extractPayload` true or false.
3. With/without `headerFilter`

All tests give me a JMS message on the queue. How do I get SI JMS to write a plain text message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it using the answer from this post [How to remove default Spring JMS Template headers when sending a message to an MQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877048/how-to-remove-default-spring-jms-template-headers-when-sending-a-message-to-an-m)

The working version is;

```
.handle(
   Jms
      .outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
      .destination("queue:///" + myQueue + "?targetClient=1")
   )
.get();
```